# Continue working for a company client after leaving the company?

Tags: professionalism, ethics, india, company-policy, clients

The current setup for my team is a team of developers that report to a manager (who is part of the company management), we take calls directly from the client and these calls happen very frequently and this leads to bonding between the company employee's and the company client. Our team client is only a single person who handles multiple projects and assigns work to us.

One of my senior team members left our company after almost 4 years of service and started working for the company client directly, while the company policy clearly states that we cannot work for any of company's client's after leaving upto 2 years. (roughly, that's what it says). My other senior team members ask me to hide this from the management/other employees as it may put our team in trouble (we won't be allowed to leave easily as it raises the same doubt on us).

I'm a junior member of the team and I don't like this unethical behavior of my senior. Do I need to let the company management know about this as this in the future may lead to loss of business for the company that I work for? How do I approach the management/client/employee? Looking for advice on ethical approaches which does not put anyone in trouble as we all make mistakes.
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "we won't be allowed to leave easily"?  Will they stop you from quitting if you want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make this your problem. **It's none of your business.**

Have you seen the contract of the ex-colleague? How do you know there are no other agreements or relationships with upper management or owners?

As for the problems while quitting:
**Nobody can stop you from quitting**, except in very special circumstances (i.e. you're vital to an ongoing project etc.)

Regarding enforcability of non compete or client poaching clauses it's safest to consult a lawyer in your locale.

Answer (score 1):

> Looking for advice on ethical approaches which does not put anyone in trouble as we all make mistakes.

If you're really not looking to get anyone in trouble, **stay out of it**.
Company management will likely discover this soon enough on their own - or they may already be aware of it (maybe they knew in advance).

I'm glad you are disappointed in the senior person signing a contract and not abiding by it, however unless you've seen it or s/he told you that they signed it, you don't actually know that they did.  Maybe that wasn't required four years ago?